# Junit test + JunitParams не читает массивы из файла csv

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, junit, test-driven-development

тест

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ParamTest {

        @Test
        @FileParameters("src/test/resources/param.csv")
        public void test(int size, String[] arr) {
            assertEquals(size, arr.length);
        }
    }
```

и файл с которого производится чтение:

```
2, asdf, asdf
```

в этом случае код работает, читается значение 2 как int другие значения попадают в массив Стрингов.

Меняем аргументы и порядок значений в файле

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ParamTest {

        @Test
        @FileParameters("src/test/resources/param.csv")
        public void test(String[] arr, int size) {
            assertEquals(size, arr.length);
        }
    }
```

Файл:

```
"asdf, asdf", 2
```

Разделяем согласно формату файла csv в кавычках одно поле, код выдает ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

Т.е. насколько я понял то если идет примитив, а потом массив, то все значения до конца файла парсяться в этот массив, если же наоборот то не получается указать где кончается массив в файле или функциональность JunitParams не позволяет этого осуществить?

Answer (score 2):

> Т.е. насколько я понял то если идет примитив, а потом массив, то все
>   значения до конца файла парсяться в этот массив, если же наоборот то
>   не получается указать где кончается массив в файле

Совершенно верно.

> или функциональность JunitParams не позволяет этого осуществить?

Позволяет, но только при использовании метода, как источника данных. В случае с CSV это невозможно.

Собственно вариантов решения два:

1. Обойтись без JUnitParams: самостоятельно парсить CSV, применив нужные вам правила чтения данных. Пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://blog.wedoqa.com/2014/03/reading-test-data-from-a-csv-file-using-junit/).
2. Использовать метод как источник данных. [Пример из документации](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/usage/SamplesOfUsageTest.java):

   ```
   public Object mixedParameters() {
       boolean booleanValue = true;
       int[] primitiveArray = {1, 2, 3};
       String stringValue = "Test";
       String[] stringArray = {"one", "two", null};
       return $(
           $(booleanValue, primitiveArray, stringValue, stringArray)
       );
   }

   @Test
   @Parameters(method = "mixedParameters")
   @TestCaseName("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}")
   public void usageOfMultipleTypesOfParameters(
       boolean booleanValue, int[] primitiveArray, String stringValue, String[] stringArray) {
   }
   ```